# ImageMagick convert format, crop and resize

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I have a large number of research pdf figures, and I need to preform the following actions in ImageMagick:

1. convert all pdf to png
2. crop png from left/top corner `x:334/y:244`; from right/bottom corner `x:214/y:340`;
   original size `2100x2100`, cropped size `1552x1552` pixels
3. resize cropped png to `240x240` pixels

Here is how it should be cropped for point 2, the pink area is what I want to have:

[image]

I was only be able to get 1st action done with my knowledge:

```
mogrify -format png -density 300 -flatten *.pdf
```

How can I do the 2nd and 3rd actions please? And do I need to run three separated commands or could they be combined into one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what exact order you need for mogrify as I do not use it. I also do not know why you need flatten Try:

```
mogrify -format png -density 300 -crop 1552x1552+344+244 +repage -resize 240x240 *.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think it crops all the corners evenly, but they should be be different as I mentioned.

Comment: The crop function cuts out a rectangle 1552 wide by 1552 high 344 in from the left and 244 from the top. Probably need a +repage to reset the canvas after the crop and I have altered the code

Comment: I get it now, and it works, as for `-flatten` with it I get white background png, transparent without it.